# Custom type mappings in EF6 using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I really don't know how to better phrase the title, so i'm sorry in advance for any incorrectness.
here is my problem:

I have the following entities:

```
public sealed class AppUser: DomainEntityBase
{

    public bool ExternalLoginsEnabled { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Email Email { get; set; }

    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public sealed class Email
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; }

    public Email(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            EmailAddress = new MailAddress(email).Address;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
           //omitted for brevity
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that, at code level i really want Email (and a couple of others i have not put here) to be treated as classes as they will be having validators and such ( i'm trying to move this to a proper DDD)
but at db level, i only need to store the email as a string.

Question: using the fluent API, how would i configure such relationship?

currently i have

```
public class AppUserConfiguration:EntityConfigurationBase<AppUser>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AppUserConfiguration"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public AppUserConfiguration()
        {

            ToTable("AppUser");

            Property(x => x.PasswordHash).IsMaxLength().IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.ExternalLoginsEnabled).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.SecurityStamp).IsMaxLength().IsOptional();

            Property(x => x.Username).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
           ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnModelCreating, define your complex type:

```
protected sealed override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.ComplexType<EMail>() 
    .Property(t => t.EmailAddress) 
    .HasMaxLength(255);

}
```

and then in your Configuration:

...

```
public AppUserConfiguration()
        {

            ToTable("AppUser");

            Property(x => x.PasswordHash).IsMaxLength().IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.ExternalLoginsEnabled).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.SecurityStamp).IsMaxLength().IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.Email.EMailAddress).IsOptional();
            Property(x => x.Username).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
           ...
        }
```